# How to pack a JMeter test plan built from code into a jar using Maven?

Tags: maven, jmeter

I'm attempting to build a JMeter test plan in Java. I can't seem to find much documentation on this process, and the resources I can find all use Maven to build the jar. I have no prior experience with Maven and cannot get my pom configuration right.

Main points of confusion:

- If my jar goes in jmeter_home/lib/ext, does that make dependencies like ApacheJMeter_core and ApacheJMeter_http a provided situation?
- There seem to be multiple Maven plugins (maven-jar, maven-assembly) with a similar purpose? Is there one that best suits my needs?
- If I want to reference a non java resource in a place outside of the jar (somewhere else in the JMeter directory), does that require special consideration when configuring your POM?
- Am I supposed to configure the jar to be executable, or does JMeter provide like a script to work with lib/ext jars?

Any insight on any of these points would be greatly appreciated.

These resources have guided me along, but I've wasted hours trying to solve this seemingly menial piece of the process..

https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/

https://github.com/piotrbo/jmeterpoc

If anyone has more resources on building JMeter test plans in code, PLEASE feel free to share!

Here's my pom.xml, I understand that there's probably some redundancy in my use of plugins and such, but that happens when you've been attacking the same problem for hours with no progress :)

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sweber</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>jmeter-plugin</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/lib
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>
                                com.sweber.Main
                            </mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <mainClass>
                                        com.sweber.Main
                                    </mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>kg.apc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-plugins-casutg</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add com.lazerycode.jmeter in the POM.

https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin

So you add this to your pom :

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
<artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.9.0</version>
<executions>
   <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
   <execution>
        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>jmeter</goal>
        </goals>
   </execution>
   <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
   <execution>
        <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>results</goal>
        </goals>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

Also, if you're going to do in IDE testing, not just mvn clean verify, you'll have to unpack Jmeter dependencies to the target dir.

Using this in the project root directory : mvn com.lazerycode.jmeter:jmeter-maven-plugin:2.9.0:jmeter

Equivalent statement for any other mvn plugin : mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goal (based on POM structure of plugin)

Comment: I see that jmeter-maven-plugin searches for test files in target/jmeter/testFiles, but what if my test plan is a jar instead? Where is that located, and what do I need to do differently to run the test that way?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly, but in IDE or using mvn verify it would make the most sense,l, to load your JMX file into the test class and use it through typical J Unit tests. 

By the way if you created your JAR in The Jmeter GUI and want to use that testplan, you can import that as your JMX file assuming your Engine class takes into consideration dependencies.

When using the SDK it's probably best to create the test plan in SDK save it or load it to run it.

Comment: I guess the reason I wanted to keep it in jar format was because I was attempting to use the Apache poi library to read test parameters from an excel spreadsheet, but couldn't figure out how to get such a dependency to work inside of a JMeter component like a bean shell script. Therefore I opted to try to configure it all in code. So maybe my real underlying confusion is in using external libraries in my test components?